# Match whole words in a java list

Tags: java

I have this PostgreSQL table for storing words:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS words
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('processed_words_id_seq'::regclass),
    keyword character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (keyword)
VALUES ('while swam is interesting', 
        'ibm is a company like bmw');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trademarks
(
   id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trademarks_id_seq'::regclass),
   trademark character varying(300) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
);

insert into words (trademarks)
VALUES ('while swam', 
        'ibm',
        'bmw');
```

Into table `trademarks` I will have thousands of registered trademarks names.
I want to compare words stored into `words` table keyword, do they match not only for a words but also for word which is in a group of words. For example:

I have a keyword `boonah qld australia` stored into `words.keyword`. I also have a trademark `aus` located in `trademarks.trademark` like `ibm` I have a word match, so I want to detect this using Java code.

First I want to select all blacklisted keywords convert them in for example List and compare `ibm is a company like bmw` with elements from the list. How I can do this not only for one word but also for a expressions?

something like this?

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {

    Optional<ProcessedWords> keywords = processedWordsService.findRandomKeywordWhereTrademarkBlacklistedIsEmpty();

    if(keywords.isPresent())
    {
        List<BlacklistedWords> blacklistedWords = blacklistedWordsService.findAll();
        List<String> blacklistedWordslist = new ArrayList<>();
        for(BlacklistedWords item:  blacklistedWords)
        {
            blacklistedWordslist.add(item.getKeyword());
        }

        ProcessedWords processedWords = keywords.get();
        String keyword = processedWords.getKeyword();

        System.out.println("Checking keyword: " + keyword);

        List<String> phrasesInDocument = findPhrasesInDocument(keyword, blacklistedWordslist);

        if(!phrasesInDocument.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Found blacklisted word in keyword: " + String.join(", ", phrasesInDocument));

            processedWordsService.updateTrademarkBlacklistedById(processedWords.getId(), String.join(", ", phrasesInDocument));
        }
    }
}

List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String doc, List<String> phrases) {
    List<String> foundPhrases = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String phrase : phrases) {
        if (doc.indexOf(phrase) != -1) {
            foundPhrases.add(phrase);
        }
    }
    return foundPhrases;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "trademarks")
public class BlacklistedWords implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "trademark", length = 200, unique = true)
    private String keyword;
}
```

As a result from the above code I get this incorrect result:

blacklisted word: `aus`. words to check: `boonah qld australia`. I get positive match which is incorrect. I don't want to match partial word. I need the whole words to match.

Can you guide me how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking Java to limit anything with regards to your check.

```
if (doc.indexOf(phrase) != -1) {
```

You are currently only asking it there is a simple match for the sting, substring or not, "aus" is even in p'aus'e.

You also have to check for it being at the end of the line or being followed by a delimiter (something like a "," "." or a space " ").

Comment: ok, can you show me code for solution, please?